# Alternative to unescape() and saving images as base64

Tags: image, svg, utf-8, base64, escaping

I am trying to convert svg to png, using the code [here](https://github.com/JuanIrache/d3-svg-to-png) as basis of my conversion.

Please note the following code (it has been shortened to only what's relevant to the error that I will describe later):

```
let svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(target); // 'target' is an svg element that is passed to us

let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

let ctxt = canvas.getContext('2d');

let img = document.createElement('img');

img.setAttribute(
    'src',
    'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData)))
);

ctxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

The above code works fine. However there is a problem with it. Notice that here is this line of code:

```
'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData)))
```

In this line of code, the `unescape()` function is used, however it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape), and I have to use an alternative. According to documentation, I should use `decodeURIComponent()`, but this not a viable solution, because when I update the code above with `decodeURIComponent()`, the result is:

```
'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(svgData)))
```

So basically I would be encoding then decoding. Which is the same as doing this:

```
'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgData)
```

Now, with the new updated code, if the source svg contains only English characters, everything is OK. However, if an svg contains characters other than English (e.g., contains the Japanese word トマト), then the next line of code, `ctxt.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` ,  throws an error. The error message is `DOMException: String contains an invalid character`.

So, to summarise so far:

1. the original code works fine with both English and non-English characters, but uses the `unescape()` function which is depracated. So I should use something else.
2. The updated code, which does not encode or decode, causes an exception when using non-English characters.

Now, *question 1*, what do I do to be able to create an image from an svg that contains non-English characters using **base64**?

As an alternative solution, I did this

```
'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svgData
```

Basically, I did not use **base64**, but rather **utf8**. This worked just fine, but I am not sure if it is the correct solution.

So, *question 2*, is using **utf8** a common practice? Is there any issue with it as opposed to **base64**?

Thank you.

---

According to the comment below from @RobertLongson , I updated the code to:

```
'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgData)
```

This worked in svg elements containg either English and non-English characters.

Now, *question 3*, is this correct?

Apologies about the basic question. I am not familiar with this. Thanks.

Comment: you must still call encodeURIComponent with uf8

Comment: @RobertLongson - Thank you. I updated the question according to your comment. Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Greeso [1] Do you really mean _"...characters other than English..."_, or is it possible that you only have problems with multibyte characters? [2] Your question is arguably seeking opinions, and is therefore liable to being closed. Can you reframe Q2 and Q3 to not ask for the _"correct approach"_ and a _"proper alternative"_?

Comment: @skomisa - Thanks you. I updated the question. And yes, my assumption was English characters are single-byte. Therefore, all non-English languages are multibyte (maybe this is inaccurate, because I think French and other Latin languages used different ASCII tables in the early days, but still where single-byte. I might be wrong though).

Comment: @Greeso See [Is there a language(s) which will require three or more bytes per character when encoded using UTF-8? Which ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3662688/2985643)

Comment: ``unescape`` might be marked _deprecated_; but officially it is not. And it will be a very very very long time before its is _removed_, because so many sites rely on it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this example I'm trying to avoid using the mentioned functions for converting to base64 and instead use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and particular the [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) function for returning the data URI. I know the code is a bit more complicated with the callbacks, but it works.

As I understand Google Translate トマト translates into .

```js
let svg01 = document.getElementById('svg01');
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas01');
let img = document.getElementById('img01');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas01.width = svg01.getAttribute('width');
canvas01.height = svg01.getAttribute('height');

let svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg01);

// create a File object
let file = new File([svgData], 'svg.svg', {
  type: "image/svg+xml"
});

// and a reader
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener('load', e => {
  let img = new Image();
  // wait for it to got load
  img.addEventListener('load', e => {
    // update canvas with new image
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
    // create PNG image based on canvas
    img01.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  });
  img.src = e.target.result;
});
// read the file as a data URL
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

```html
<p>SVG embedded:</p>
<svg id="svg01" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 20" width="300" height="60">
  <rect width="100" height="20" fill="silver" rx="5"/>
  <text font-size="7" x="50" y="10" text-anchor="middle"
  dominant-baseline="middle">Japanese word: トマト </text>
</svg>
<p>Canvas image:</p>
<canvas id="canvas01"></canvas>
<p>PNG image:</p>
<p><img id="img01" /></p>
```